# webview lose focus after I click outside it and never zoom in or out again android

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I have a major problem using webview in android

I have the following layout

RelativeLayout
-- TextView
-- ImageView
-- RelativeLayout
------Webview

when I enter the webview has focus and I can zoom in and out, when I click on Textview or Imageview and back to webview I can't zoom in or zoom out

I have tried a lot of things
 - set all other view not focusable and not clickable 
 - set onTouch listener to parent view and set my webview to request focus

but nothing work, can anyone help please

Comment: Did you try `WebView.requestfocus();` in the `onTouch()` ?

Comment: yes I have did it, I have checked if it not focused then requestfocus, but it always find it focused and didn't do anything, and also zooming not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happen to me because I was using view pager with DepthPageTransformer and add it one of it's fragment my webview, the problem solved when I use the default Transformer of the view pager